How to suppress ExtendedMessage: Attribute 'for' of label component with id* messages in the websphere for zos 8.5.5.13 log?
How to suppress ExtendedMessage: Attribute 'for' of label component with id* messages in the websphere for zos 8.5.5.13 log? Changing the application is not an option for now.
I didn't find any jvm-level parameter that worked.

I use the =info: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.=off to supress the messages for the log
